# How long does a disguise last?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So I'm playing a Summoner synthesist in a world where magic is outlawed. This means if he's seen in his eidolon suit it's basically a death sentence.

To get around this, I was going to get him to use the disguise skill to look like 'himself' even when fused with his eidolon. Looking online I see there's some debate about whether you can take 10 or take 20 with disguise, but for the sake of argument let's say I could take 10 hours or so to take 20.

In this situation, how long would this disguise last? would I never need to roll another disguise check again to look like 'myself'? Or would I have to do it every time my eidolon was summoned, or every x hours or what?

Also, I'm sure I read somewhere that you get a bonus to disguise if the target wears a distinctive outfit or uniform, but I can't remember where I read it. Anyone know what that's from?

Comment: Another option - have the eidolon look normal and be a smaller character concealed "inside" it, think Rhino, Men In Black, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A disguise lasts until your appearance changes again. You're putting on make-up, prostheses, altering clothing to fit differently, and other physical changes. When you undo those changes, you're no longer disguised.

So, every time you fuse with your eidolon, you'd need to disguise yourself again to look like "yourself".

Finally, I'm not aware of any bonus for your target having a distinctive outfit. But if such a thing exists in a sourcebook somewhere, it would almost certainly be for when you're using a disguise to *impersonate* someone the observer already knows, where wearing an outfit distinctive to them would make observers less likely to look closely to confirm that you are *who* you appear to be. That wouldn't apply in this case, since you're trying to hide *what* you are, not trick observers about *who* you are.